# How can I unpause a command and send all standard output to a log file

Tags: bash

So there's the usual way of pausing commands with CTRL+Z and you can then do "bg 1" or whatnot to resume the command, and that works just fine.

What if I started a command that sends a bunch of output to stdout, but I don't want to see that stuff anymore after "unpausing" the command. Could I do something similar to "bg 1 > file.log"?

Answer (score 4):

This is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593724/redirect-stderr-stdout-of-a-process-after-its-been-started-using-command-line/593764#593764) which has instructions for sending output to `/dev/null`.

To send output of a running program to `/tmp/file.log`, for example, do the following:

From a second terminal, use `ps` to get the process ID of your program.

Type `touch /tmp/file.log` to create an empty file for your output to go into.

Type `gdb -p [PID]` using the process ID from `ps`.

At the `(gdb)` prompt type these commands:

```
p dup2(open("/tmp/file.log",1),1)
p dup2(open("/tmp/file.log",1),2)
detach
quit
```

In response to the `dup2` commands, you should see "`$1 = 1`" and "`$2 = 2`". You should see output cease on the other terminal and you should be able to `cat` or `tail -f` the log file (or use `ls -l` repeatedly and see the size increase).

Now you can suspend your process using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> and resume it in the background using `bg 1` (or whatever the job number happens to be).